# Process blocked at console.log when combining readline and puppeteer

Tags: node.js, readline, puppeteer

The following code will be blocked forever before `console.log("this line.....");`.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
async function main() {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    rl.close();
    await browser.close();  
    console.log("this line will not be executed.");
}
main();
```

Moving `rl.close()` below of `console.log` solves this problem, removing `browser = .....` and `await browser.close()` did the same.

Is this a bug of puppeteer? Or does there are some mechanism I don't understand?

Puppeteer version: 1.11.0
Node.js version: 10.14.2
OS: Windows 10 1803

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is worth to be reported as an issue to the puppeteer GitHub repository. Something really weird happens to stdin and event loop after this combination (Chrome does exits, but the Node.js remains, and after the Ctrl+C abort the prompt appears twice in the Windows shell as if ENTER was buffered till the exit).

FWIW, this issue disappears if `terminal` option of `readline.createInterface()` is set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks! I submitted this issue [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3829). Will update this question when there are updates on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not completely understand how ASYNC/AWAIT works in js.

If you use **await** inside an **async** function it will pause the async function and wait for the Promise to resolve prior to moving on.

A code inside your **async** function will be processed consistently as if it were synchronous, but without blocking the main thread.

```
async function main() {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(); // will be executed first
    rl.close();// will be executed second (wait untill everithing above is finished)
    await browser.close(); // will be executed third (wait untill everithing above is finished)
    console.log("this line will not be executed."); // will be executed forth (wait untill everithing above is finished)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question. The problem I faced is browser.close() takes *forever* to resolve, and this happens only if I call `rl.close()` before `await browser.close()`. I think this is specified to puppeteer, as if I remove `browser = await puppeteer.launch();` and change `await browser.sleep()` to another promise(like a sleep promise which relay on setTimeout) then the problem will be gone.